# Will Apple reject our app if I support iOS 3.x?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-3.x

I'm aware that if I build our app on Xcode 4.5, We won't be able to submit our app to the App Store not to mention we won't even be able to run the thing on the device with iOS3.x.

Not what I want to clarify is that, if we decided to still support iOS3.x do we just use Xcode 4.3 or any Xcode lower than 4.5 and voila I can submit it to the app store and Apple won't give a care and approve the app if it supports iOS3.x or not since it was built using a lower version of Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you provided an iPhone 5 screenshot, you should be able to submit app that backward supports iOS 3.x .

But why do you want to support iOS 3.x ? Not many devices are using this iOS version .

Comment: Wait, I thought apple rejects apps that has iPhone 5 screen support and at the same time support iOS3.x? In order to develop on iPhone 5 screen which you advertise on the screenshot you have to use Xcode 4.5, where the lowest iOS support is 4.3. Manually inputting 3.x would give you and error or warning that says cannot create binary for armv6. Something along those lines I think. Correct me if I'm wrong btw.

Comment: partially correct. you can still include a `Default-568h@2x.png` in your project. Also, the screenshot is added when you submit your App to App Store in `iTunes Connect`. use Xcode 4.3 .

Comment: Basically this is how it goes, if I use Xcode 4.3 and build our app from there, our app that supports iOS3.x will not be rejected. Am I right to assume this?

Comment: Yes. But currently Apple only processes the App with iPhone 5 screenshot.